# How to stop the page refresh after click on button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have a asp.net page where i am using javascript code in Edit.aspx and declared a method in it add course() as soon as the add course method is completed the control goes to the Button click event which is in Edit.aspx.cs and after the button click is completed the whole page refreshes

Comment: can u show aspx and javascript code?

Comment: if you are not doing any work in Click event on Edit.aspx.cs , just return false on client click of button.

Comment: try `OnClientClick="return course();"` in `course()` method must be return `true` or `false` and no ajax.

Answer (score 3):

Your question says that you are working on client side then use

```
OnClientClick="course(); return false;"
```

.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to call javascript method use OnClientclick()

and if you want call both the methods use onclick event to call the code behind method i.e method in aspx.cs and inside use this code

```
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", course());
```

Answer (score 1):

asp.net web forms will always do a postback on a runat="server" button click.   that is how it reaches the code behind (.cs file).  for client side clicks you can either use aspx ajax or jQuery click or javascript onclick functions to prevent postbacks.  For this very reason more and more asp.net developers are moving to asp.net mvc.

Try just creating a simple html button and doing and onclick to run you javascript function:

```
<button onclick="javascript:some_js_function();">Click Me</button>
```

or jQuery:

```
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

in you document.ready:

```
$('form').on('click', '#btn', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    some_js_function();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to call any server side event on button click its better to use normal `html` `button` control.

Replace

```
  <asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

With

```
   <input type="button" value="Submit">Submit</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your addcourse javascript function always return false and asp:button OnClientClick="return addcourse();"

** Example **

```
    <asp:button id="Add" runat="Server" OnClientClick="return addcourse();"/>
```

** JQuery **

```
function addcourse()
{
//your code here 
return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your button on Edit.aspx have a property **runat="server"** remove it and your post back stops